# Creating a dividend forecast overview with stocks paying dividend in each upcoming month

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, stock, forecast

So I have been trying something but I just cannot get it working. Hope you can help me out.
I have a forecast overview (see Stock forecast image). In this overview I want to see the dividends per stock per month. Of course I could fill in everything manually but I'd like to automate it a bit.

Currently in this forecast I want to see the upcoming 12 months. For the months I use the following formula: =EDATE(TODAY(),0). This results in december 2023.

[Stock forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2kq3.png)

For this to work I need a different table where I specify in which month a stock is paying dividend. Also I need to specify how many dividend each company is paying per month. Somewhere I also need to multiply the amounts of stocks and the dividend per month. In the first image the stocks symbols are in column A but for the seperate table I think it is better to have them as columns. I use the following formula for this: =TRANSPOSE(A1:A5)

See the image below for this table.

[Dividend per month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeOFn.png)

For the sake of this example let's say I have these 4 stocks and each stock is paying $1 dividend each month. I own 5 stocks of each company.

Now my question is: what formula do I need to calculate how many dividend is being paid per month per stock displayed in the forecast?

I tried so many things but just can't figure it out.

I tried many different formulas. Also used ChatGPT but that cannot help out either. Here is one example:

=IFERROR(SUMIFS(1, 2, 3, INDEX(4, 0, MATCH(5, 6, 0)), 7), 0)

1. Range containing dividends (second table)
2. Range containing the months in a list (second table)
3. Reference to the month in the row of the forecast overview (first table)
4. Stock per column (second table)
5. Stock in the row of the forecast overview (first table)
6. Stock per column (second table)
7. Stock in the row of the forecast overview (first table)

Maybe this example is totally wrong. I also tried other things but I think that is not relevant. You should get a good idea of what I'm trying to achieve here.